# Swift: Using a variable to describe an UIViews

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, popup

I have multiple custom pop up views that I call (to set it up, animate the pop up and animate the dismiss) but I want to have one variable that I can replace in the multiple functions that can be set by a switch statement with one variable. So I don't have 4+ of every function with the same code but different uiView names. How is that done please?

```
var myPopupView:NotePopUpView!
var myInformationPopUpView:InformationPopUpView!
var myDatePopUpView:DatePopUpView!
var myPainDiagramView:PainDiagramPopUpView!

func notePopUpCalled() {
   if (myPopupView != nil) {
    self.myPopupView.view.removeFromSuperview()
   }

// making different size pop up for different screens
  var popUpWidth = GlobalConstants.ScreenStats.screenWidth - 60

  if UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.size.width > 320 {
    if UIScreen.mainScreen().scale == 3 {
      popUpWidth = 320
    } else {
      popUpWidth = 320
    }
  } else {
    popUpWidth = 283
  }

self.myPopupView = NotePopUpView(frame: CGRect(x: 20, y: 350, width: popUpWidth, height: 334))
myPopupView.center = self.view.center
self.view.addSubview(myPopupView)
showAnimate()

}
```

Comment: Think [protocols](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Protocols.html) or superclasses.

Comment: That is good but it doesn't reduce the code like I had hoped.

Answer (score 0):

Generally when it is necessary to apply one method on different types recommended to use generics.

```
    func setupView<T: UIView>(view: T) {
     //Make all setups
}
```

Also you can use `as?` operator to downcasting your view types to `UIView`.

Hope it helps.